# javascript code to extract values in curly braces with specific keyword in line

Tags: javascript, regex, loops, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a set of text files in Google cloud storage(new files come to storage at every 5 minutes[batch processing]). what I want to do is put it into Google BigQuery via Dataflow. In dataflow, we can directly import text files in cloud storage to Google BigQuery(in my case I want batch processing). It requires a javascript code to transform textfiles in GCS into a table in bigquery.
Here is my sample of my one text file.

[image]

I want to write **javascript code to**  select topic name is **Bat** and the values between curly braces into Bigquery table.According to above sample below is the required one.(BigQuery schema will be added later)

[image]

Im really new to javascript(actually this is the first time) and I want to implement a javascript function to do this.I don't know select the topic name Bat** in line.

Below is what I tried.(please fix, if this is wrong)

```
function transform(line) {

const paramsPattern = /[^{\}]+(?=})/g;
let new = line.match(paramsPattern);

var values = new.split(',');

var obj = new Object();
obj.ID = values[0];
obj.AGE = values[1];

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);

return jsonString;
}
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

let new = line.match(paramsPattern);

you should not assign this to a variable new... new is special.

This is a regex that would work with your example: https://regex101.com/r/tBHRIY/1

Here is an example:

```js
const testLine  = 'Topic:Bat [0] at offset:216812{"ID":51255125, "NAME":6}';

function transform(line) {
    const paramsPattern = /({[\s\S]+})/g;
    const match         = line.match( paramsPattern );

    if ( line.indexOf( 'Bat' ) === -1 )
        return null;

    if ( match === null )
        return null;

    // This will verify that the json is valid ( it will throw ) but you can skip this and return match[0] directly if you are sure it is valid
    return JSON.stringify( JSON.parse( match[0] ) );
}

console.log( transform( testLine ) );
```

Edit: sorry i missed checking for BAT, added

Comment: thanks @stefantigro. I want to only select line if topic name is "Bat".(ignoring other topic names). To do this have to get word after Topic: if that word equals Bat then select that line.(ignoring all the other topic names)

Comment: I've edited my answer, would that work? Instead of just 'Bat' you could also do `line.indexOf( 'Topic:Bat' ) === -1`

Comment: Thanks a lot. i will check after adding this part.   var obj = new Object();
obj.ID = values[0];
obj.AGE = values[1];

Comment: You don't need to add that part. The data retrieved is a valid JSON already. Also that won't work probably as my regex selects all the contents of the curly braces. Why do you want to do `var obj = new Object(); obj.ID = values[0]; obj.AGE = values[1]` ?

Comment: @kevin ... take into account that any `indexOf` based approach for determining a specific topic is error prone ... e.g. `Bat` versus `Bats` or `Battery` and  `Cat` versus `Cats` or `Catering`. There should be a regex that a least checks for a topic's key value pattern like with `if ((/Topic:Bat\s+/).test(line)) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

If it comes to reliability, as well as convenience and/or maintainability one should think about a more generic approach that does [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) a list of lines/strings and in addition [takes even a specific topic into account](https://regex101.com/r/AD31R6/1/) by assembling the correct regex ...

```js
const fileData = `
  Topic:Cat [0] at offset:216712{"ID":55689534,"NAME":6}
  Topic:Cat [1] at offset:216719{"ID":55689524,"NAME":6}
    Topic : Bat [0] at offset:216716  {"CODE":94762151097,"AGE":32}  
  Topic:Cat [0] at offset:216713{"ID":55689524,"NAME":6}
  Topic:Bat [1] at offset:216723{"CODE":947080272531,"AGE":43}
  Topic:Cat [1] at offset:216738{"ID":55689525,"NAME":6}
`;
const dataItemList = fileData.split(/\n/);


function getTopicSpecificDataCaptureRegX(topic) {
// see also: [https://regex101.com/r/AD31R6/1/]

//return (/^\s*Topic\s*\:\s*Bat[^{]+(\{.*\})\s*$/);
//return (/^\s*Topic\s*\:\s*Cat[^{]+(\{.*\})\s*$/);
  return RegExp('^\\s*Topic\\s*\\:\\s*' + topic + '[^{]+(\\{.*\\})\\s*$');
}

function collectTopicSpecificData(collector, dataItem) {
  const result = dataItem.match(collector.regX);
  if (result !== null) {

    collector.list.push(JSON.parse(result[1]));
  }
  return collector;
}


console.log(
  '"Cat" specific data list : ',
  dataItemList.reduce(collectTopicSpecificData, {

    regX: getTopicSpecificDataCaptureRegX('Cat'),
    list: []

  }).list
);
console.log(
  '"Bat" specific data list : ',
  dataItemList.reduce(collectTopicSpecificData, {

    regX: getTopicSpecificDataCaptureRegX('Bat'),
    list: []

  }).list
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```